# std::isalpha not recognizes utf8?

Tags: c++, c++11

why the code below does not recognize the string "abraço" as alphabetic?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool isApha(string word) {
  for (auto c : word) {
    if (std::isalpha(c))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

int main() {

  string test= "abraço";
  if(isApha(test)){
    cout<< "Is alpha." << endl;
  } else {
    cout<< "Is NOT alpha." << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you been given any reason to believe that `std::isalpha` is intended for use with unicode codepoints, or with text encodings other than ascii?

Comment: @Xirema I don't believe the C++ Standard mentions the ASCII encoding wrt this or any other function.

Comment: How would testing individual bytes of a multi-byte encoding produce useful results? Since it only sees one byte at a time, it has no way to know if the complete character is alphabetic or not.

Comment: @Xirema — `isalpha` works just fine with **any** single-byte character encoding. It is not restricted to ASCII.

Comment: it's spelled `isAlpha`, not `isApha`

Comment: @PeteBecker `std::isalpha` doesn't have a chance here.  ç is represented by 2 bytes in a UTF-8 std::string, and std::isalpha only gets to see them one at a time.  You need to use a wide string (and set the right locale) as shown in the linked answer.  I believe support for the UTF-8 locale is platform specific so YMMV.

Comment: @PaulSanders -- yes, that's why I said **single-byte character encoding**. UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding. Wide strings won't handle it, either; to get a fixed-length encoding you have to convert the UTF-8 codes to UTF-16 and ignore the surrogate pairs, or convert them to UTF-32.

Comment: @PeteBecker In the code as posted by the OP, you can say `std::basic_string<wchar_t> test= L"abraço";` and then go from there.  But as you say, converting UTF-8 to UTF-16 or UTF-32 is a separate (although straightforward) problem.

Comment: @PaulSanders -- again I don't see what your comment has to do with what I said. **You** injected UTF-8 into this discussion; now you're off on yet another tangent. If you have a proposed solution to the original question, don't address it to me; address it to the question. My comment was **only** about the apparent assertion that `std::isalpha` can only be used with characters encoded in ASCII.

Comment: @PeteBecker Oh I _see_.  Your comment was addressed to Xirema.  I misunderstood your point, sorry.  Please take my comments as addressed to the **question**, everybody.